# Websocket problem with vueJS and laravel for a basic post posting application

Tags: laravel, vue.js, sockets, websocket

I'm trying to make a simple posts application with realtime data pushing, I'm amature at vue so sorry if the problem is basic. there's two problems actually (but the case is one)

1. I'm not able to get the posts I directly refreshed
2. I'm not able to post because of the main datapushing issue, I knew that because before I started trying to add datapushing it was working fine.

So I'm expecting to post the Tweets and get the tweets updated.

In console I'm getting these:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:6001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OU1t4ob' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

> GET http://127.0.0.1:6001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OU1t4ob net::ERR_FAILED 404 (Not Found)

I have ran

> php artisan websockets:serve

and I have Event for tweet creation `return new Channel('tweets');`

I'm not able to download `composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors` because I'm getting

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

this is the Home page:

```
<template>
    <AuthenticatedLayout>
      <template #header>
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">Home</h2>
      </template>

      <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-4xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg relative px-2 pt-4 pb-14">
            <form @submit.prevent="submitTweet">
              <textarea
                v-model="tweet.body"
                name="body"
                class="focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 resize-none shadow-none border-none h-60 w-full"
                placeholder="What's on your mind?"
                autocomplete="off"
              ></textarea>
              <PrimaryButton type="submit" class="ml-4 absolute right-6 bottom-6">
                Post
              </PrimaryButton>
            </form>
          </div>
          <Tweets :tweets="tweets" @tweet-deleted="deleteTweet" @tweet-liked="likeTweet" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </AuthenticatedLayout>
  </template>

<script>
import AuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue';
import PrimaryButton from '@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue';
import Tweets from './partials/Tweets.vue';
import { Head } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import axios from 'axios';
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue';
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

export default {
  components: {
    AuthenticatedLayout,
    PrimaryButton,
    Tweets,
  },

  setup() {
    const tweet = ref({
      body: '',
    });

    const tweets = ref([]);

    const echo = new Echo({
      broadcaster: 'socket.io',
      host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
      client: io,
    });

    watchEffect(onInvalidate => {
      axios
        .get('/tweets')
        .then(response => {
          tweets.value = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('An error occurred while fetching tweets.');
        });

      echo.channel('tweets').listen('.tweet.created', data => {
        tweets.value.unshift(data.tweet);
      });

      echo.channel('tweets').listen('.tweet.deleted', data => {
        const index = tweets.value.findIndex(tweet => tweet.id === data.tweet.id);
        if (index !== -1) {
          tweets.value.splice(index, 1);
        }
      });

      onInvalidate(() => {
        echo.leaveChannel('tweets');
      });
    });

    const submitTweet = () => {
      axios
        .post('/tweets', tweet.value)
        .then(response => {
          tweet.value.body = '';
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('An error occurred while posting the tweet.');
        });
    };

    const deleteTweet = (id) => {
      axios
        .delete(`/tweets/${id}`)
        .then(response => {
          console.log('Tweet deleted successfully!');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('An error occurred while deleting the tweet.');
        });
    };

    const likeTweet = (id) => {
      axios
        .post(`/tweets/${id}/like`)
        .then(response => {
          console.log('Tweet liked successfully!');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('An error occurred while liking the tweet.');
        });
    };

    const unlikeTweet = (id) => {
      axios
        .delete(`/tweets/${id}/like`)
        .then(response => {
          console.log('Tweet unliked successfully!');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('An error occurred while unliking the tweet.');
        });
    };

    return {
      tweet,
      tweets,
      submitTweet,
      deleteTweet,
      likeTweet,
      unlikeTweet,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Tweets Partial:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <h3 class="text-3xl font-bold pt-6 pb-3">Latest Tweets</h3>

      <div class="flex flex-col gap-4">
        <Tweet
          v-for="tweet in tweets"
          :key="tweet.id"
          :name="tweet.user.name"
          :joined="tweet.user.created_at"
          :posted="tweet.created_at"
          :body="tweet.body"
          :likes="tweet.likes"
          @edit="editTweet(tweet.id, $event)"
          @delete="deleteTweet(tweet.id)"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>

<script>
import Tweet from "@/Components/Tweet.vue";
import { ref, watchEffect } from "vue";
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import axios from "axios";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

export default {
  components: {
    Tweet,
  },
  setup() {
    const tweets = ref([]);

    const echo = new Echo({
      broadcaster: "socket.io",
      host: window.location.hostname + ":6001",
      client: io,
    });

    watchEffect(onInvalidate => {
      axios
        .get("/tweets")
        .then(response => {
          tweets.value = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("An error occurred while fetching tweets.");
        });

      echo
        .channel("tweets")
        .listen(".tweet.created", data => {
          tweets.value.unshift(data.tweet);
        })
        .listen(".tweet.updated", data => {
          const index = tweets.value.findIndex(tweet => tweet.id === data.tweet.id);
          if (index !== -1) {
            tweets.value.splice(index, 1, data.tweet);
          }
        })
        .listen(".tweet.deleted", data => {
          const index = tweets.value.findIndex(tweet => tweet.id === data.tweet.id);
          if (index !== -1) {
            tweets.value.splice(index, 1);
          }
        });

      onInvalidate(() => {
        echo.leaveChannel("tweets");
      });
    });

    const editTweet = (id, body) => {
      axios
        .put(`/tweets/${id}`, { body })
        .then(response => {
          // Do something if needed
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(`An error occurred while updating tweet ${id}.`);
        });
    };

    const deleteTweet = id => {
      axios
        .delete(`/tweets/${id}`)
        .then(response => {
          // Do something if needed
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(`An error occurred while deleting tweet ${id}.`);
        });
    };

    return {
      tweets,
      editTweet,
      deleteTweet,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Tweet Component:

```
<template>
    <div class="flex bg-white shadow-sm rounded-lg w-full">
      <div class="flex items-start px-4 py-6 w-full">
        <img
          class="w-12 h-12 rounded-full object-cover mr-4 shadow"
          :src="avatarUrl"
          :alt="name + ' profile picture'"
        />
        <div class="w-full">
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
      <h2 class="text-lg font-semibold text-gray-900 -mt-1">{{ name }}</h2>
      <small class="text-sm text-gray-700">{{ posted }}</small>
    </div>
    <p class="text-gray-700">Joined {{ joined }}</p>
    <div v-if="editing">
      <textarea v-model="editedBody" class="border p-2"></textarea>
      <div class="mt-4 flex items-center">
        <PrimaryButton @click="saveTweet">Save</PrimaryButton>
        <SecondaryButton @click="cancelEdit">Cancel</SecondaryButton>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="mt-3 text-gray-700 text-sm" v-else>{{ body }}</p>
    <div class="mt-4 flex items-center">
      <div class="flex items-center mr-2 text-gray-700 text-sm mr-3">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-heart"><path d="M20.84 4.61a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78 0L12 5.67l-1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78 7.78l1.06 1.06L12 21.23l7.78-7.78 1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0-7.78z"/></svg>
        <span class="pl-3">{{ likes }}</span>
      </div>
      <!-- <DangerButton v-if="editable && owned" @click="deleteTweet">Delete</DangerButton> -->
      <PrimaryButton v-if="canEditTweet && !editing && owned" @click="editTweet">Edit</PrimaryButton>
    </div>
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
   import PrimaryButton from "@/components/PrimaryButton.vue";
  import SecondaryButton from "@/components/SecondaryButton.vue";
  import DangerButton from '@/components/DangerButton.vue';

export default {
    components: {
    PrimaryButton,
    SecondaryButton,
    DangerButton,
  },
  props: {
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    body: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    joined: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    posted: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    likes: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    editable: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false,
    },
    owned: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      editing: false,
      editedBody: '',
    };
  },
    computed: {
        avatarUrl() {
            return `https://i.pravatar.cc/150?u=${this.name}`;
        },
        canEditTweet() {
            return this.editable;
        },
    },
    methods: {
      deleteTweet() {
        this.$emit('delete-tweet', this.id);
      },
      editTweet() {
        if (this.editable) {
          this.editing = true;
          this.editedBody = this.body;
        }
      },
      saveTweet() {
        this.editing = false;
        this.$emit('edit-tweet', { id: this.id, body: this.editedBody });
      },
      cancelEdit() {
        this.editing = false;
      },
    },

  };
</script>
```